# uses-sdk in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm a little confused about something.

I wrote an app and tested it on an LG Ally with the following specs:

Android version:  *2.2.2*

Kernel version:  *2.6.32.9*

Build number: *FRG83G*

Now I'm trying to install it (via adb install AppName.apk) on an HTC with the following specs:

Android version: *2.3.3*

Kernel version: *2.6.35.10-gc0a661b HTC-kernel@and 18-2#1*

Build number: *4.24.651.1 CL61076*

and I get an error like 'error parsing package'

Here's where I get confused.  I wanted to try duplicate the problem.  So I created an emulator AVD with the specs:

Android version: *4.0.3*

Kernel version:  *2.6.29-g46b05b2 vchtchetkine@vc-irv #28*

Build number:  *google_sdk-eng 4.0.4 MR1 302030 test-keys*

And....I am able to install my app successfully with the adb install command that will NOT install the app on the HTC.

I don't understand why I'm able to use 'adb install' to put it on the LG Ally and the emulator but I get the parse error on the HTC.

I thought I might need  in the AndroidManifest but then why am I able to install on the emulator without it?

My manifest is below (I removed the activity definitions for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.mj.molepatrol"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">


  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

      <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

  </application>

      <uses-permission
      android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR">
      </uses-permission>

  <uses-permission
       android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR">
  </uses-permission>

  <uses-permission
       android:name="android.permission.EDIT_CALENDAR">
  </uses-permission> 

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Maybe just acrivate unknow sources in your settings

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I tried that with the HTC and it didn't help.

Comment: Your question title mentions the `uses-sdk` tag but does not mention anything about it in the content itself... it'd be helpful to have that information.

Comment: Alex Lockwood

That's very strange.  I added my uses-sdk line at the bottom of my post but it didn't show up.

The statement I think I need is:

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

But the larger question is, why am I able to install and run the app in the emulator WITHOUT the uses-sdk line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible problem for this is that you are using a feature that is not available to the device. Such as a camera or NFC.

You have only set `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` right?

There will be something in the manifest that the htc doesn't like, please post your **AndroidManifest.xml** file so we can see specifics and figure it out for you

Comment: SmartLemon

I tried adding my AndroidManifest to this comment, but I exceeded the allowed number of characters.  I will try to add it to my original question, but those edits haven't been showing up.

My app  uses the Google APIs for Calendar, Places and Maps.

I am NOT setting minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion in the manifest.

Comment: You should be setting both minSdk and targetSdk, this could be where its going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10">`

It will solve your problem. Because, I read this documentation about uses-sdk,

**Caution**: *If you do not declare this (uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion) attribute, the system assumes a default value of "1", which indicates that your application is compatible with all versions of Android. If your application is not compatible with all versions (for instance, it uses APIs introduced in API Level 3) and you have not declared the proper minSdkVersion, then when installed on a system with an API Level less than 3, the application will crash during runtime when attempting to access the unavailable APIs. For this reason, be certain to declare the appropriate API Level in the minSdkVersion attribute.*

Source: [Android Developers Website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)